# Prove $g(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(y^2x)f(x) dx$ is bounded and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This question is from a practice qualifying exam. Here's my attempt (I'm a bit stuck on the continuity part):

Since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $f$ is bounded. Then:

$$|g(y)| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(y^2x)f(x) dx| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\sin(y^2x)|f(x)| dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| dx$$

So $g$ is bounded. For continuity, let $y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$.

$$|g(y)-g(z)| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(y^2x)f(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(z^2x)f(x) dx| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[\sin(y^2x)-\sin(z^2x)\right]f(x) dx|$$

Now $f$ is bounded so $|g(y)-g(z)| \leq M\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\sin(y^2x)-\sin(z^2x)|dx$

Since $\sin$ is a continuous function, can I just make $|\sin(y^2x)-\sin(z^2x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{M}$, and be done? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: There's no guarantee that an $L^1$ function is bounded. Use the dominated convergence theorem.